# System("pause") in Unix?

Tags: c++

I normally use a debugger such as `cgdb` so I thankfully hadn't needed to resort to `system` calls for debugging, until now.

I have a binary that takes around 30 minutes to load in `gdb` and frequently crashes the debugger thereafter, probably due to the very large number of symbols. This makes my normal workflow (loading `gdb`, adding breakpoints, identifying problem variables, etc.) untenable.

In windows I would at this point begin adding lots of `cout` and `system("pause")` (poor man's breakpoint) statements throughout my code; but how do I do this in a unix-like environment?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You may want to read from `cin` to get a poor man’s `pause`
– it will wait for you to type an <kbd>Enter</kbd>,
rather than resuming while you’re getting coffee (as `sleep()` will).

Answer (score 6):

I sometimes resort to this

```
#define BRK()  do { printf("%s %d\n", __FILE__, __LINE__); getchar(); } while (0)
...
BRK();  // Stop and wait for enter
```

Also, function instrumentation might help:
GCC allows to hook into every function enter/exit, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281739/automatically-adding-enter-exit-function-logs-to-a-project

Comment: Maybe your C is different from mine, but I either have to put parens in the define or delete them in the call for this to work. Otherwise, that's a handy tip!

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the correction, added parens

Answer (score 5):

Same thing for `cout`/`cerr`, and you can just use `sleep()` - see `man 3 sleep` or `man 3 usleep` for more info.